# Problem trying to resolve type in Windsor

Tags: castle-windsor

I have the following items in my solution:

```
public interface IHandle<TEvent>
{
    void Handle(TEvent event);
}

public interface IPresenter<TView>
{
}

public abstract class Presenter<TView> : IPresenter<TView>
{
    protected view;

    public TView View
    {
        set { view = value;}
    }

    // snip...
}

public interface IMyPresenter : IPresenter<IChangeRequestReviewManagementView>
{
    // snip...
}

public class MyPresenter : Presenter<MyView>, IMyPresenter, IHandle<CustomEvent>
{
    // snip...
}
```

And have the following registration for Windsor to register the presenters:

```
container.Register(AllTypes.Of(typeof(IPresenter<>))
                    .FromAssemblyNamed("Project.Presentation")
                    .WithService.Select((type, baseType) => new Type[] {GetInterfaceFromConvention(type)})
                    .Configure(config => config.LifeStyle.PerWebRequest));

private static Type GetInterfaceFromConvention(Type type)
{
    return (from found in type.GetInterfaces()
    where found.Name.Equals("I" + type.Name)
    select found).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

This works perfectly and I can resolve the presenters in my pages using:

```
public IMyPresenter Presenter
{
    set
    {
        presenter = value;
    }
}
```

Using this http://code.google.com/p/sneal/wiki/AspNetWindsorModule, the problem comes when I try to wire in the support for handling events supplied via a separate EventAggregator which calls implementers of IHandle<>. I added this registration:

```
container.Register(AllTypes.Of(typeof(IHandle<>))
                    .FromAssemblyNamed("Project.Presentation")
                    .BasedOn(typeof(IHandle<>))
                    .WithService.Base());
```

As this works for other areas that implement IHandle<> but after adding this the container cannot no longer resolve IMyPresenter to MyPresenter, so I must be missing something?!

Comment: you just added the new registration, without changing the first one?

Comment: Yes the first one is untouched

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I now see what the problem is (or at least I suppose I do - didn't run the code myself).

The problem is that you break SRP by making your `MyPresenter` do two jobs.

Then, when you register your components you try to register `MyPresenter` twice, and the first registration wins (2nd time it won't get registered).

To fix this you should refactor `MyPresenter` to do just one thing. This will most likely require you to introduce `MyPresenterHandler` that will have dependency on `MyPresenter` to do its job.

This way you will have no conflicting registrations and everithing should work just fine.